# Bluetooth RSSI to Distance

Tags: bluetooth, nrf52832

I'm trying to find the distance between two bluetooth beacons which are typically in the distance of 60cm or less. Direction is not an issue, I'm only looking to figure out the distance between the beacons and there will be no interferences such as walls/objects in between. Is it possible to detect the distance through RSSI Measurements? and if so what will be the expected accuracy?

Comment: Many have asked similar questions and the general answer is: it cannot be done. You forget that the antennas as more sensitive in some directions and less in other directions. That makes it impossible to determine the distance between devices as it depends on how their antennas are oriented relative to one another. The new BT 5.0 standard might improve this but since it uses multiple antennas it is also a lot more complex.

Comment: just to cite a few: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/333666/connect-rf-module-to-phone-to-find-distance-between-them https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/31100/distance-between-2-arduinos-using-rf-links https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/223003/how-this-device-electronic-anti-lost-anti-theft-flashlight-measure-distance https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/51515/how-to-measure-distance-from-moving-object-using-rfid

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate. I have limited control over my environment i.e one of my beacons is stationary and the other beacon might only move within the 60cm and no walls/objects in between. More like a water tap wants to know whether a bucket is right below it or not and if not how distant it is from it?

BT 5.1 looks promising but the chipsets won't be in production until at least early next year. @MarcusMüller

Comment: as said, this is a multiple-questions-duplicate, as the answer is always the same. RSSI is not a distance indicator, and attenuation being mappable to distance simply isn't how wireless channels work. Distance estimation through RSSI doesn't work, and the explanation given under those linked answers applies here completely unmodified.

Comment: on one hand, yes, you can somewhat detect distance; if one is in the next town over, it will be zero. That's a bit of a joke, but in all seriousness, the accuracy is very very very low to the point of being useless. So while you can get a boolean of distance info, you can't get a fraction. With a lot of sampling, you might be able to divide the readings into 2-4 rough "zones" of distance with unidirectional antennas, but again, it's going to be pretty flaky for most use-cases.

Comment: Okay, I will resort to other alternates then :)